# understanding grammar implementation in java

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

I was searching for implementation of context free grammars in java to do some operations on them related to compilers design course like LL(1), SLR parsing and stuff like that and I found this [implementation](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Lothaire/AppliedCW/ProgrammesJava/BibliJava/Grammar.java). The grammar main method is reading the grammar from a file where I write the grammar and the code to parse it, the problem is that I cannot write the grammar in the right way for the code to understand, for example I cannot write the epsilon transition whenever I write `epsilon` or `ε` it is considered as terminals. Could anyone  please help me to write the grammar in the right way for the code to understand for example this grammar:

```
E  -> T E'
E' -> + T E' | epsilon
T  -> F T'
T' -> * F T' | epsilon
F  -> ( E ) | id
```

Comment: It looks like this program only accepts single `char`s as the names (I forget what they're supposed to be called), have you tried changing `E'` to `e` and `T'` to `t`?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a nonterminal for the empty string and have that terminal produce the empty string literal. E.g., `EMPTY -> ''` and everywhere you want the empty string transition just use `EMPTY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the code file that you linked to, it has in a comment what the correct notation to use is:

The `ETF` grammar :
        `E -> E + T`
        `T -> T * F`
        `F -> (E) | char` .

and

The modified version of the `ETF` grammar which
      is LL(1) :
        `E -> Te`
        `e -> +Te | ""`
        `T -> Ft`
        `t -> *Ft | ""`
        `F -> (E) | char` .

This was pasted straight out of the file you linked. Is it not the answer?